# Wide angle lenses that fit a Rebel T3i

Tags: lens, wide-angle

Will a Canon EF 28mm f/2.8 IS USM Wide Angle Lens - Fixed work on a Rebel T3i? What does IS UMS mean?

Comment: Isn't this a question for a retailer rather tnan for SE?

Comment: @PinhollowEuri No. Questions about camera equipment are definitely [on topic](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Photo.SE.

Answer (score 0):

> Will a Canon EF 28mm f/2.8 IS USM Wide Angle Lens - Fixed work on a Rebel T3i?

**Yes.** Any Canon EF lens will work on an EOS camera, which includes the Rebel T3i.

> What does IS UMS mean?

IS stands for image stabilization. USM means the lens has an ultrasonic autofocus motor, which is desirable because it's faster and quieter than some other AF motors.

Answer (score 0):

The EF 28mm f/2.8 IS USM is only a wide angle lens if used on a Full Frame camera like a 6D or 5D Mk III.

On a T3i "crop camera" it would be a normal lens and no longer have a wide angle field of view.

Comment: It's true that *every* lens is subject to the usual 1.6x crop factor on the T3i, and in this case that means that the 28mm lens will have a field of view similar to a  45mm lens on a full frame camera. Nevertheless, the lens will work just fine.